# How would I print a randint multiple times without it printing the same number multiple times

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to make a small dice rolling program. I'm trying to get a randint printed multiple times without it being the same number multiple times. Sorry if it's a stupid question

```py
from random import randint
dice_sides = input("Input the dice that you want rolled") #use the format "dx" where d stands for dice and x is represents the sides of the dice for ex. "d20"

num = int(input("Input the number of dice you want rolled"))

if dice_sides == "d20":
    print(str(randint(1, 20))* num)
```

Comment: Please give sample output to help us understand "...without it printing the same number multiple times"

Answer (score 1):

Put the print statement inside a for loop.

```
for _ in range(num):
    print(randint(1, 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a list of rolls with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  Use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) to display it nicely:

```py
from random import randint

sides = int(input('Number of sides on die? '))
num = int(input('Number of dice to roll? '))
rolls = [randint(1, sides) for _ in range(num)]
total = sum(rolls)
print(f'{num}d{sides} = {rolls} {total=}')
```

Output:

```
Number of sides on die? 20
Number of dice to roll? 5
5d20 = [6, 6, 9, 18, 7] total=46
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you are just starting out with Python. The two answers you have so far are great but let's make them a little clearer for you.

Basically, you need the loop (or a list comprehension but let's save that one!) from https://stackoverflow.com/a/78095067/21655737:

```
from random import randint
dice_sides = input("Input the dice that you want rolled") #use the format "dx" where d stands for dice and x is represents the sides of the dice for ex. "d20"

num = int(input("Input the number of dice you want rolled"))

if dice_sides == "d20":
    for _ in range(num):
        print(randint(1, 20))
```

As a next step, let's make your code a little more generally useful by folding in parts of https://stackoverflow.com/a/78095082/21655737:

```
from random import randint

sides = int(input('Number of sides on die? '))
num = int(input('Number of dice to roll? '))

for _ in range(num):
     print(randint(1, sides))
```

From my point of view, now that I've got this bit of code, I might think about making your code a function, using list comprehension, and returning the list so you can do other things with it.